# Unable to run Ubuntu 17.10 live (cannot open /dev/sda)

Tags: boot, live-usb, 17.10

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 17.10 (final) on my Dell Precision 5520. Installing from a usb thumb drive.

When booting (either from "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu"), I get to the Ubuntu loading screen (with the dots underneath), but after a long wait get dumped to a BusyBox prompt. If I press `esc` to see the boot output, the line `cannot open /dev/sda` is repeated many times.

Other information:

- I've tried creating the bootable usb via two methods, Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator and Etcher.
- I've tried both uefi and legacy boot methods.
- I do not have Intel Rapid Store Technology enabled in BIOS.

Update:

Using boot option `nolapic` got me to the desktop. However, apps were randomly crashing/not opening. I noticed a flood of `SQUASHFS` errors when I peeked at the other tty's. Then I booted with both `nolapic` and `acpi=off` and things seemed to calm down. I don't have confidence to proceed with the installation, however, given all the weirdness. It seems that the kernel with Ubuntu 17.10 just does not support my SATA controller very well. Is that accurate?

**Update 2:**
I managed to get it installed by switching the boot method of the laptop (in BIOS settings) from UEFI to Legacy boot. I still had to specify `nolapic` when booting.

Answer (score 0):

During the initial boot from the USB, you may need to use a kernel parameter "nomodeset" to get past the point you are freezing at.  The procedure is listed at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions and basically

- When you see the screen that says "Try Ubuntu..." press <kbd>F6</kbd>
- Scroll down using the arrow keys until "nomodeset" is highlighted
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to continue the "Try Ubuntu..."

Comment: `nomodeset` didn't make a difference, but this led me to try some of the other options. In particular, `nolapic` helped me boot to the desktop. Then I was experiencing random crashes, and noticed a flood of `SQUASHFS` errors in the other tty's. Booting with `nolapic` and `acpi=off` seemed to get things to a somewhat stable state. going to update my question

Comment: Ah.  acpi apparently can be really rough to debug - I have not had many issues with my Dell 5521.

Answer (score 0):

The Squash file errors could be read/write errors to the HD on your laptop.
I would suggest installing a new HD.
I had the same error messages after I installed Ubuntu on an old Pentium 2 desktop. I installed a new HD, reinstalled Ubuntu and restarted the desktop. The Squash file errors disappeared. The desktop has a SATA drive.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but there's nothing wrong with the hard drive.